# expresion for the sum of the pentagonal numbers

Tags: calculus

How do I find the expresion for the sum of pentagonal numbers? 
I am doing a research paper on this and I have tried using the sn expresion for aritmetic series and replacing the variables but I am left with the expresion for the nth pentagonal number.

Comment: Since the $k$-th pentagonal number is $\frac{3k^2-k}{2}$, the formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The $n^{th}$ pentagonal number $p_n=\frac{3n^2-n}2$

So sum of first $n$ pentagonal number

\begin{align}
S_n&=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{3n^2-n}2\\&=\frac32\sum^n_{k=1}n^2-\frac12\sum^n_{k=1}n\\&=\frac32\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac12\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\&=...
\end{align}

Then you know what to do.

Comment: We get a very nice looking expression. It might be interesting to know whether there is a simple "reason" why the average of the first $n$ pentagonals is the $n$-th triangular.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Maybe we can think about it.

Comment: For OP's reference: :Let's denote the $n^{th}$ triangular number be $T_n$, then $T_{2n-1}=p_n+T_{n-1}$, that is, $p_n=T_{2n-1}-T_{n-1}$ .